# How can I start a C# process using Process.start() with sandboxing?

Tags: c#, permissions

In my program, I need to load some code at runtime, and run them as new processes to test their behavior.

Concretely, a user will provide some input and output examples, and I want to find the code that can take in the input and produce the output. Thus I need to run the code in my code database one by one to find out the correct one.

However, since some code in my code database will access my windows and do something adverse, e.g. call bing search, shut down windows explorer...

What I do now:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.Filename = ...
p.StartInfo.Arguments = ...
...
p.Start();
```

How can I run p in a safe environment? By safe, I mean disallowing it to access my windows. (It's ok if the process p want to access my windows and through exception in the safe environment.)

Thanks!!

Comment: Please have a look on AppDomains

Comment: Thanks! I asked the question because I'm wondering if I can solve the problem by simply modifying my current implementation which uses Process. (Re-do everything using AppDomain can be a little bit painful for me.)